# Angular useHash=true, exclude specific routes from it

Tags: angular

So I have the following line of code in my app module

```
 RouterModule.forRoot(routes, {useHash: true}),
```

which appends hash for all of my routes, which works fine for me. but some API
is trying to do a redirection to my application on a specific route and it is not including a hash at the end so we can imagine it is doing a redirection on the following route

```
http://localhost?some_query_parameters
```

but this doesn't work because of `useHash: true` so how can I achieve this redirection or how can I exclude at least one single route from `useHash: true`

Comment: You can't. Everything after the hash is managed by Angular, everything before is managed by your server. This means you can't control the behavior of a single route at Angular level. The only solution is to do it on the server side.

Comment: Thanks for the quick response, could you explain more on doing it on the server side?. really appreciate your help

Comment: I would if I could, but I'm a JS dev focused on Angular. I don't know much about servers, and you didn't specify which one you're using. I suggest you edit your question to append the correct tags to it, so that someone else can answer you !

Comment: may be this helps (please read the article in between) : http://joeljoseph.net/angular-6-deploy-on-apache-server-by-solving-404-not-found-error-on-page-refresh/

Answer (score 1):

If you require something like this you can achieve it with a redirection in your server.
Take a look at how to configure htacess file if your server is apache.

However once you can do it, I believe, there won't be any reason to use hash location strategy anymore which is the root cause of this situation.